# Running "net user "user" /domain" command and read results in classic asp

Tags: cmd, asp-classic, command

First of all sorry for poor english.
I am using Classic ASP for simple things on my network. I want users to view their domain password expire date on our intranet page. Intranet page runs classic asp.

on CMD or powershell

`"net user "username" /domain"`

command gives the result. On asp page I need to run this command and read the result of password expire date. 
Can you pls help me. 
Thanks.

Comment: You can do with a LDAP query.

Comment: Can you show ne how?

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect output into a text file, you can read the file from asp:

```
Set w = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
w.Run "cmd /c net user > c:\temp\output.txt", 0, true ' send output into file 

Set s  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = s.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\output.txt", 1) ' read file

o = f.ReadAll
f.Close

response.write o
```

Of course, this will require access of asp account to execute given command and 
read/write access to the file.